# Why I can't change variable in it.c?

Tags: stm32, c, c++, keil, hal

I have stm32vldiscovery project. I want to use external interrupt by PA0 (user button).
When I press the button (PA0), then function EXTI0_IRQHandler must set ldOn equal 0. But ldOn always is 1. Debuger shows what function EXTI0_IRQHandler runned on. ldOn change value to 0, and again stay equal 1. Why?
Have this code:
**main.c**

```
#include "main.h"
...
uint8_t ldOn = 1;

int main(void)
{

  HAL_Init();

  SystemClock_Config();

  MX_GPIO_Init();
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD4_GPIO_Port, LD4_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  while (1)
  {
        if(ldOn == 0)
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD4_GPIO_Port, LD4_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  }
}
```

**it.c**

```
#include "main.h"
...
extern uint8_t ldOn;
void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void)
{
  ldOn = 0;
  HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_0);
}
```

When I used stm32f4-disc1 board, this construction works perfectly...

Comment: Hint: Try the volatile qualifier

Comment: @doynax didn't help.On stm32f4-disc1 board this code works perfectly.

Comment: What are the compiler and linker flags? I suspect your two boards may have different defaults in the setup.

Comment: Changing a non-volatile variable in an interrupt is Undefined Behviour, so it can produce different results. Next: put the extren declaration in the header.

Comment: Problem was in iwdg. Controller did reset every some miliseconds... I made full erase and reset configuration bits. After that the code did work perfectly. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either declare variable ldOn as volatile 
or
Remove optimizations from compilation
and check

It should work.
Even after using volatile keyword/removing optimization from compilation
if code is not working then you have to triple review your code and check whether somewhere else variable is being modified.

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36483011/variable-value-not-updated-by-interrupt-on-stm32f4-discovery)

Comment: Problem was in iwdg. Controller did reset every some miliseconds... 
I made full erase and reset configuration bits. After that the code did work perfectly. Thanks for the help.